# Does an online Android application generated by GeneXus connect to the database?

Tags: genexus

I'm using GeneXus X Evolution 3 and I want to install it in a production environment.
The web app works well, but the android one does not. It fails when starting.
Does the android app connect to the database hosted in the server? If so, how do I need to configure ports or what do I need to set in the datastore properties?

Comment: Hi Javier, Stackoverflow is an english Q&A site, we are all kindly asked to post in english here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The native android application does not access your database. It accesses REST services hosted in your applications server and those connect to the database.
So what you have to set is the [Services URL property](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?21146). 
If you have problems accessing the REST services, you may have some [issues related to URL Rewrite](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?18398) or other [common issues](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwikibypageid?14575).

Comment: Thanks Armin. That solved part of my problem. I also copied *.svc files (CSharp XCopy doesn't copy them) and followed the instructions in your link. Now is all up and running. Thanks again!